# User permissions on certain views based on roles

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3.  Please excuse my terminology.  We assign roles to certain people at work, then we use Windows authentication to determine what roles a user has.  Lets say the roles are RoleA, RoleB and RoleC.  So now I get a list of roles for a user.  Lets says that UserA belongs to RoleA and RoleB.  Some of my views need to be authenticated as not everyone can view certain views.  Lets say that ViewA can only be viewed by users that belong to roles RoleA and RoleB.  How would I do this?  What would I need to look into?  When a user that does not belong to these roles tries to access the views then he/she should be redirected to an error page.

Also, I need some sort of helper method to check these roles as well to be used in my views to hide/display certain controls.  Where is the best place to use this?

Any sample code / articles would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[Authorize(Roles = "RoleA,RoleB")]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    return View();
}
```

And if you want to check roles in the view:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("RoleA"))
{
    <div>This will be visible only to users in RoleA</div>
}
```

Comment: Isn't it better to pass if user is in role through view model?

Comment: @Darin: How would I add the roles to the roles collection?

Comment: @Darin: And where would I specify that it must go to a generic error page if the user does not have access rights?

Comment: @Brendan, by default the Authorize attribute will redirect to the login page. You could write a custom action filter deriving from the default one and redirect to the desired page.

Comment: @Darin: I was just told that our roles are handled by IIS.  How would I get the user's identiry and if he/she belongs to roles?  Have you got sample code there please?  How would you implement this code to help me in my scenario above?

Comment: @Brendan, if you are using Windows authentication you may read the following article: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-cs