# MVC3 - Placing Role Athorization on @Html.Actionlink()

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html.actionlink

What is the best and/or most efficient way to place Authorization on an @Html.Actionlink so so those not authrorized DO NOT SEE THE LINK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Administrators")) { Html.ActionLink(...) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Mystere Man was indeed first to the punch here and deserves credit, but to provide additional info this has been asked here in other similar scenarios:

[User permissions on certain views based on roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091218/user-permissions-on-certain-views-based-on-roles)